# Can someone explain this sentence from Dartmouth's German page?

Tags: english, semantics, second-lang-acquisition, germanic-languages, german

Was perusing the page ([you can find it here](https://www.dartmouth.edu/~deutsch/Grammatik/WordOrder/WordOrder.html)), I came across the paragraph "That said, word order is a complex aspect of language, never wholly mastered by non-native speakers.

What is the idea behind this? Does that mean that as a Native English speaker I have mastered concepts that foreign speakers will not master? What would some examples of this be? And is reverse true, as I am learning German no matter what level of proficiancy I obtain a native will understand better than I?

Comment: I think the viewpoint expressed there is only one opinion. People don't have perfect data about the acquisition of grammar by non-native speakers; we can aggregate the most common errors and determine what general tendencies of error non-native speakers may have based on their language of origin, but we don't have any absolute evidence that non-native speakers can "never" master complex aspects of second languages. (The theoretical reasons for suspecting this might be the case are also controversial.) Anyway, "mastery" is not well-defined.

Comment: Generally speaking, there's a logic mistake in that sentence, it is impossible to prove that something will _never_ happen.

Comment: The quote is a bit of an exaggeration, but there is truth to the idea that non-native speakers are granted less [poetic licence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artistic_license).  As far as German specifically, I can say that the rules for word order differ between the formal language, the informal language and the dialects, but that's true of many features of all languages.